# Unmarshal Nested JSON Object With Go

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm making requests to an API that returns a JSON structure that is difficult to parse, especially in Go. Here is the gist of the data in tabular form:

| Ticker | Jan 3 | Jan 4 | Jan 5 | Jan 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 182.01 | 179.70 | 174.92 | 172 |
| NFLX | 597.37 | 591.15 | 567.52 | 553.29 |

However, the requested data is completely unordered and unnecessarily nested:

```json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "NFLX",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-04",
        "price": 591.15
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "AAPL",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-03",
        "price": 182.01
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "AAPL",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-06",
        "price": 172
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "NFLX",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-05",
        "price": 567.52
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "AAPL",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-05",
        "price": 174.92
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "NFLX",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-06",
        "price": 553.29
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "NFLX",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-03",
        "price": 597.37
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "AAPL",
      "data": {
        "date": "2022-01-04",
        "price": 179.7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to create a map using Ticker as the key and a numpy-like array of prices - ordered by descending date - as the value, such as:

```golang
[{Ticker:NFLX Prices:[553.29 567.52 591.15 597.37]} {Ticker:AAPL Prices:[172 174.92 179.7 182.01]}]
```

To accomplish this, I'm creating several intermediate structs, performing small operations on each along the way to get it into this final format. I can't help but to think there is a better solution. But for now, here is my current implementation:

```golang
func NewRecord(id string, prices []float64) Record {
    return Record{
        Ticker: id,
        Prices: prices,
    }
}

type Record struct {
    Ticker string
    Prices []float64
}

type Records []Record

func (rs *Records) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {

    type entry struct {
        Date  string  `json:"date"`
        Price float64 `json:"price"`
    }

    type payload struct {
        EntrySlice []struct {
            Ticker string `json:"id"`
            Entry  entry  `json:"data"`
        } `json:"records"`
    }

    var p payload
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &p); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create a DataFrame Like Map Using Ticker as the Key
    dataframe := make(map[string][]entry)
    for _, x := range p.EntrySlice {
        dataframe[x.Ticker] = append(dataframe[x.Ticker], entry{
            x.Entry.Date,
            x.Entry.Price,
        })
    }

    // Sort Entries (DataFrame Values) By Date Descending (i.e. Most Recent First)
    for _, entry := range dataframe {
        sort.Slice(entry, func(i, j int) bool { return entry[i].Date > entry[j].Date })
    }

    // Drop dates to create an array-like structure indexed by ticker
    var records Records
    for id, data := range dataframe {
        var fx []float64
        for _, entry := range data {
            fx = append(fx, entry.Price)
        }
        records = append(records, NewRecord(id, fx))
    }

    *rs = records

    return nil
}
```

This code works. But as someone relatively new to Go, I feel like I'm doing a lot more than what is necessary.

I'd like to learn what others are doing in these situations to find a method that is both idiomatic and parsimonious.

playground: https://play.golang.com/p/p3Ft0Ts4oSN

Comment: There isn't a lot you can improve here. One thing you can do is to use  `append(dataframe[x.Ticker], x.Entry)` instead of reconstructing the struct.

Comment: assuming 1. you're always querying a range of dates 2. the dates are always are in days 3. the number of records you receive is not exponentially lower than the total number of days 4. each day has a unique value for a unique ticker. If all of the above are true you can range from the largest to lowest day - they can be figured out when traversing the data for the first time. This way you save on the presumed O(nlogn) sort for a ~O(n) ordering.

Comment: @Kelsnare Thank you! 1, 2, & 4: True. 3: True, number of records >= number of days. So I should sort on date first immediately after unmarshalling, right? Side note - how can you tell it would be that much faster? I assumed creating a map would be faster as there are fewer values assigned to each key. I'm not CS so I'm often lost here.

Comment: It's not a good idea to put your business logic in `UnmarshalXYZ` func. It makes your code hard to test and understand. I'd recommend you to have 2 separate steps, unmarshalling and converting(group by field, sort by date, etc). https://goplay.tools/snippet/BSb9WXfJvMy

Comment: following up on the advice from @Kelsnare, I separated my business logic from the unmarshaller and sorted immediately after the unmarshalling. My code looks a lot cleaner and more maintainable now. https://play.golang.com/p/nO0PZpba1lc